# How to add javascript and d.ts file to angular 2 project

Tags: angular5, protobufjs

I want to integrate protobufjs into my angular 2 project, according to [here](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js#pbts-for-typescript), first I install protobufjs, then use the CLI and my .proto file to generate the static code (both js file and related d.ts file), e.g. I get a.js and a.d.ts.

Then I put a.js and a.d.ts to somewhere, and import a.d.ts to component file which use it. The import instruction is as below:

```
import { model } from "path to the a.d.ts file";
```

My question is:
where should the a.js be placed? and how angular 2 application link the a.d.ts to the underlying a.js file?

Note: I don't want to include a.js to index.html. and angular 2 application use yarn as package manager and webpack as module bundler.

Very appreciated for any help.